# vb.net Get PID of another application

Tags: vb.net, pid

I'm trying to find the PID of an application that I only know the name of is there some way to get PID from GetProcessByName?

Answer (score 1):

[`Process.GetProcessesByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an array of [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects, each of which has an [`Id`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which is the PID.

```
Dim firefox = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")
For Each proc In firefox
    Console.WriteLine("pid={0}", proc.Id)
Next
```

Since there can be multiple processes returned, you will need to have some way to select the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice `Linq` example... Replace `PROCESSNAMEHERE` with your `process` name... The variable `proc` holds the process object and from there you can do anything with it. This object is an `Array` of any process's it finds...

```
  Dim proc() As Process = Process.GetProcesses().Select(Function(p) p).Where(Function(n) n.ProcessName = "PROCESSNAMEHERE").ToArray
    If proc IsNot Nothing AndAlso proc.Count > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, From pr In proc.Select(Function(x) x.Id)))
    End If
```